# BindingExpression path errors while using completely different Datatemplates in ListView with DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm using very different DataTemplates in the one ListView with the help of DataTemplateSelector. It's for blog client app, so page looks like: 
post(1 object) -> comments options(1 object ) -> comments(many objects). All of them in the one ListView which is easy and flexible. But I receive "BindingExpression path error" while scrolling deep into comments (to 10+ comment down). Properties of objects (options and post) is not found in comment object (and back when I scroll up). It looks like it's related to ListView virtualization and ListView trying to use previous datatemplate for next objects in the list. However I don't understand why it's happening. The data is displayed as it should, but errors in output window is annoying. Maybe I missed something? It looks like I should force ListView to call DataTemplateSelector before trying to resolve properties from the object, but how?

While watching comments it appears once: 
[image]

While scroling back to top:
[image]

Comment: This might sound stupid, but does your binding class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface? i.e. ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Do you mean items in the collections? Yes, all of them.

Comment: Are you by chance using any converter inside your list XAML. Please check if the data getting binded after 10+ comment are in correct format and arent `null`. It might be related to the response retrieved from your server since it got binded perfectly for first 10 items right.

Comment: It's not related to data for sure because appears in the every post and populating comments without a such list structure does not generate any errors. It's exactly related to list items virtualization.